# Ubuntu Live Persistence Full - Unable to login

Tags: boot, login, live-usb

I have Ubuntu 23.04 Live on USB with 4 GB persistence.

While installing software (python-pip) received an error that persistence space full. Thereafter unable to do GUI Login!

Is it possible to do a terminal login (devoid of GUI)?

ALT+CTRL+F3/F4/F7 does not work!

Thanks
rraj

Comment: See my answers at [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2489638).